# css to align table to center on ios mail mobile

Tags: html, css, html-table

building an email with html css. i'm using tables which works fine on Gmail Outlook and Yahoo clients. on ios mail in mobile all tables are aligned left.
I need it to centered.

this is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html data-editor-version="2" class="sg-campaigns" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
  <style type="text/css">

  </style>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #F9FBFF; margin:auto;">

  <table align="center" style="background-color:#FFFFFF; width:609px; height:55px; padding-left: 10px;  border:1px solid #E7F7FF; display:block;">
    <tbody>
      <tr style="height:50px;">
        <td style="vertical-align: middle; ">
          <div style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Helvetica';font-weight: 500; ">Hate Speech</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="https://www.kidas.net/post/toxicity-in-video-games">
            <img style="height:auto !important; padding: 8px 0px 0px 5px;" title="Abusive language based on prejudice" width="15" src="http://cdn.mcauto-images-production.sendgrid.net/6e0d08eb67685199/9451cd9d-023e-4c4f-a679-84200923b3b6/15x15.png">
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you find an answer? I also have the same problem

Comment: Hi. i added to the body padding:0 which did not solve completely the problem but it's definitely better.